# Access to Java servlet request using JavaScript on the client side

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, request

Hello everybody I am trying to access a forwarded request with java script, the code fractions of both side look like this:

Client side

```
function addRow() {
var numRows = document.getElementById("request").getAttributeNode("numOfExt");
var table = document.getElementByName("extensionTable");

var allExtensions = new Array();
allExtensions = document.getElementById("request").getAttributeNode("extensions");

for ( var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    cell1.innerHTML = allExtensions[i];
}
}
```

Servlet

```
request.setAttribute("numOfExt", extensionHandler.getExtensions()
            .size());
request.setAttribute("extensions", extensionHandler.getExtensions()
            .toString());

// forward the httpServlet
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,
            response);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And the error would be...?

Comment: What does that mean? What do you want to do exactly? "access a forwarded request with java script" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That's not how servlets work. Read the [SO wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to start. You don't access attributes from the `request` object. You access them from the html (from jsp) that is returned, that might have been populated by the request attributes.

Comment: Excuse me for being not precise, I am completely new to web development and have searched the internet for 2 hours before asking.

I want to post some data from the server where the java code is located to the javascript function embedded in a jsp file to set up a table dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remember to have a form (hidden) or include an action in your page:

```
<form name="formname" action="servlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="someParam">
</form>
```

Then from your javascript, invoke your servlet:

```
document.formname.someParam.value = "hello world";
document.formname.submit();
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer